# resolving unknown error to send email through API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to API scripts and trying to send emails to addresses listed in Sheet sendTo!B2 onwards.
The messages composed are in composeMessage!A2 onwards. My script gives an unknown error. what am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help

function composeNsend()

```
{
  // Fetch the message
  var messageRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("composeMessage").getRange("A2"); 
  var message = messageRange.getValue();
  {
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sendTo").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  
    // Send Email.
    var message = message;
    var subject = 'ALERT for New 365d Low';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

My message composed does have blank lines

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some extra brackets in the middle of your code. Remove them and the function will work. Edited the code to loop through rows and flag sent rows. The code below worked for me:

```
function composeNsend()

{
 
  let curr_ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let subject = 'ALERT for New 365d Low';

  let message_sheet = curr_ss.getSheetByName("composeMessage");
  let last_message_row = message_sheet.getLastRow();

  //get 2D array of values
  let message_array = message_sheet.getRange("A2:A"+last_message_row.toString()).getValues();
  //convert to 1D array
  let messages = message_array.map(itm=>itm[0]);
  
  let email_sheet = curr_ss.getSheetByName("sendTo")
  let last_email_row = email_sheet.getLastRow();
  
  //get 2D array of values
  let email_array = email_sheet.getRange("B2:B"+last_email_row.toString()).getValues();
  //convert to 1D array
  let emails =email_array.map(itm=>itm[0]);
  //get flags column
  let flags = email_sheet.getRange("C2:C"+last_message_row.toString()).getValues().map(itm => itm[0]);
  //empty array for new flag values
  let new_flags = [];
  
  //choose lowest of last rows in messages and emails, don't send emails without body or email address
  let last_row = Math.min(last_email_row,last_message_row);
  
  //for loop to send emails, add flag on column C for each email sent
  //subtract 1 from last row because array starts from second row
  for(let i=0; i<last_row-1; i++){
    let curr_flag = flags[i];

    //send email only for rows without sent flag
    if(curr_flag != 'sent'){
      let message = messages[i];
      let emailAddress=emails[i];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
    new_flags.push(['sent']);
    }

  //write new flags to sheet 
  email_sheet.getRange("C2:C"+last_row.toString()).setValues(new_flags);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it does send the email but only to the first email address on the list of recipients and sends only the first message from the list of messages. also it sends the same email at every trigger. Perhaps id need to add a flag (showing the email time and email addresses) every time the email is sent so it doesnt send it again. Im not sure how to do that

Comment: Do you need to loop over a number of rows? Currently this code only takes cells A2 and B2. You could add a for loop. How do you determine which message to send to which recipient? You could add a third column where you write 'sent' after you send the email successfully and next time the trigger runs you run it over rows that don't have 'sent' in the third row. I can add that if you can explain how you decide which message to send to which recipient.

Comment: All the messages (A2 onwards) go to all the recipients (B2 onwards) but only once    I’d appreciate if you’d show me how to flag which messages were sent. Would the api get triggered on the server side even if the file is not active on the browser?

Comment: Yes, the trigger can be time based, it could work every day, every hour, every five minutes etc. The file doesn't need to be open in a browser for the time based trigger to work. There are onEdit and onOpen triggers that work when the sheet is edited, or opened, respectively.

Comment: Edited my answer and now the function loops through rows of emails and messages, puts flags in column C of email sheet